# Grabbing Certain Data from a ResultSet

Tags: python, html, dataframe, parsing

Given a ResultSet that has been scraped from the web, I am left with something like this:

```
[<td class="head1" colspan="18"><div class="headTD1"> [-]</div><div class="headTD0"> </div><div class="headTD2">NBA - Monday, March 27th</div></td>, <td class="head1x" colspan="0" style="z-index:2;"></td>]
[<th class="time c1 center-game-started"><div>03/27</div><div class="time">04:10p</div></th>, <th class="team c3 game-started"><div>Dallas</div><div>Indiana</div></th>]
[<th class="time c1 center-game-started"><div>03/27</div><div class="time">04:10p</div></th>, <th class="team c3 game-started"><div>Milwaukee</div><div>Detroit</div></th>]
[<th class="time c1 center-game-started"><div>03/27</div><div class="time">04:40p</div></th>, <th class="team c3 game-started"><div>Houston</div><div>New York</div></th>]
[<td class="head1" colspan="18"><div class="headTD1"> [-]</div><div class="headTD0"> </div><div class="headTD2">MLB Spring Training - Monday, March 27th</div></td>, <td class="head1x" colspan="0" style="z-index:2;"></td>]
[<th class="time c1"><div>03/27</div><div class="time">06:07p</div></th>, <th class="team c3"><div>LA Dodgers</div><div>LA Angels</div></th>]
[<th class="time c1"><div>03/27</div><div class="time">06:40p</div></th>, <th class="team c3"><div>Cleveland</div><div>Arizona</div></th>]
[<th class="time c1"><div>03/27</div><div class="time">06:45p</div></th>, <th class="team c3"><div>Oakland</div><div>San Francisco</div></th>]
[<td class="head1" colspan="18"><div class="headTD1"> [-]</div><div class="headTD0"> </div><div class="headTD2">NHL - Monday, March 27th</div></td>, <td class="head1x" colspan="0" style="z-index:2;"></td>]
[<th class="time c1 center-game-started"><div>03/27</div><div class="time">04:37p</div></th>, <th class="team c3 game-started"><div>New Jersey</div><div>NY Islanders</div></th>]
[<th class="time c1"><div>03/27</div><div class="time">07:07p</div></th>, <th class="team c3"><div>Colorado</div><div>Anaheim</div></th>]
[<th class="time c1"><div>03/27</div><div class="time">07:07p</div></th>, <th class="team c3"><div>Edmonton</div><div>Arizona</div></th>]
```

The table that I am grabbing data from is like a bunch of tables within one massive table with no real separation within the HTML.

What I would like to achieve with this data is to be able to search for a substring in one of the td tags, and if that substring is found, grab all the th tags below until you reach the next td tag.

This is how I have initially created the ResultSet "cells":

```
for row in soup_table.tbody.findAll("tr"):
    cells = row.findAll(['th', 'td'])

for index in range(len(cells)):
    if #cells[index] contains substring "MLB"
        for #all th tags underneath until next td tag
            # data[col_names].append(cells[index2])
```

I'm assuming I have to do something in the above manner, but I just not have been able to figure it out. This is the first time I have a result set that has different tags. Would it be best to separate these into separate ResultSets and have some separate indexing to try and grab the correct data?

Sample format/layout of what the html would like like before being parsed. Did my best to try and simplify but still show enough information of what to expect:

```
<tbody>
    <tr id="header1">
        <td class="head1" colspan="18">
            <div class="headTD1"> [-]</div
            <div class="headTD0"> </div>
            <div class="headTD2">NBA - Monday, March 27th</div>
        </td>
        <td class="head1x" colspan="0" style="z-index:2;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="event1">
        <th class="time c1 center-game-started">
            <div>03/27</div>
            <div class="time">04:10p</div></th>
        </th>
        <th class="team c3 game-started">
            <div>Dallas</div>
            <div>Indiana</div>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="event2">
        <th class="time c1 center-game-started">
            <div>03/27</div>
            <div class="time">04:10p</div>
        </th>
        <th class="team c3 game-started">
            <div>Milwaukee</div> 
            <div>Detroit</div>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="header2">
        <td class="head1" colspan="18">
            <div class="headTD1"> [-]</div>
            <div class="headTD0"> </div>
            <div class="headTD2">MLB Spring Training - Monday, March 
            27th</div>
        </td>
        <td class="head1x" colspan="0" style="z-index:2;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="event3">
        <th class="time c1">
            <div>03/27</div>
            <div class="time">06:07p</div>
        </th>
        <th class="team c3">
            <div>LA Dodgers</div>
            <div>LA Angels</div>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="event4">
        <th class="time c1">
            <div>03/27</div>
            <div class="time">06:40p</div>
        </th>
        <th class="team c3">
            <div>Cleveland</div>
            <div>Arizona</div>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="header3">
        <td class="head1" colspan="18">
            <div class="headTD1"> [-]</div>
            <div class="headTD0"> </div>
            <div class="headTD2">NHL - Monday, March 27th</div>
        </td>
        <td class="head1x" colspan="0" style="z-index:2;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="event5">
        <th class="time c1 center-game-started">
            <div>03/27</div>
            <div class="time">04:37p</div>
        </th>
        <th class="team c3 game-started">
            <div>New Jersey</div>
            <div>NY Islanders</div>
        </th>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your goal efficiently if you make use of 'find_all()' and 'find_next_siblings()'.

```
# Find all td tags
td_tags = soup.find_all('td')

# Loop through each td tag and check if it contains the substring "MLB"
substring = 'MLB'
for td_tag in td_tags:
    if substring in td_tag.text:
        # Once the substring is found, find all following th tags until the next td tag
        th_tags = []
        for next_tag in td_tag.find_next_siblings():
            if next_tag.name == 'td':
                break
            elif next_tag.name == 'th':
                th_tags.append(next_tag)

        # Do something with the th tags
        print(th_tags)
```

This code first finds all td tags in the HTML using the find_all method. It then loops through each td tag and checks if it contains the desired substring. If it is found, it searches for all following tags using the find_next_siblings method until it encounters the next td tag. If a th tag is encountered, it is added to a list of th tags. Finally, the list of th tags is printed or can be processed further (whatever your intentions are).

Alternative solution:

```
th_tags = []
substring = 'MLB'
substring_found = False
for cell in cells:
    if substring_found and cell.name == 'td' and 'head1x' in cell['class']:
        continue
    elif substring_found and cell.name == 'td':
        break
    elif substring_found and cell.name == 'th':
        th_tags.append(cell)
    elif cell.name == 'td' and substring in cell.text:
        substring_found = True
```

Comment: When I attempted to use this, I wasn't receiving the right data. It seems that the find_next_siblings() is only finding the last td tag located from the original list. Only outputs "<td class="head1x" colspan="0" style="z-index:2;"></td>".

Comment: I believe the issue is that the th tags technically aren't siblings of the td tags. I will update my question to help reflect better what the html side of things would look like.

Comment: I see. In that case you could maybe just use a flag to indicate if you are inside a relevant block of data, and a for loop going over all the "cells". I edited my answer and added a new solution.

Comment: So even with the new solution, the next tag the loop goes over will still be the same td tag. Is it possible to ignore adding that td tag to the original ResultSet based off of the class name "head1x"?

Comment: Yes, the problem with the solution was that the first occurrence after the substring is another td tag (the one with the "head1x" class), causing the loop to terminate prematurely without finding any th tags. I changed the solution so that it now skips over that specific td tag.